# SQL Server and intermediate materialization?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

*After reading [this interesting article](http://dataeducation.com/cursors-run-just-fine/) about intermediate materialization - I still have some questions.*

I have this query :

```
SELECT    *
FROM  ...
WHERE       isnumeric(MyCol)=1  and ( CAST( MyCol AS int)>1)
```

However, the where clause order is **not** deterministic.

So I *might* get exception here.( if he first tries to cast `"k1k1"` )

I assume this will solve the problem

```
SELECT MyCol 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT foo From MyTable WHERE ISNUMERIC (MyCol ) > 1 ORDER BY MyCol ) bar
WHERE
    CAST(MyCol AS int) > 100
```

- why does putting `top 100 + order` will change VS my regular query ?

I read in the comments  :

> (the "intermediate" result -- in other words, a result obtained during
>   the process, that will be used to calculate the final result) will be
>   physically stored ("materialized") in TempDB and used from there for
>   the remainder of the user, instead of being queried back from the base
>   tables.

- what difference does it makes if it is stored in tempDB or queried back from the base tables? it is the **same data** !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The supported way to avoid errors due to the optimizer reorganizing things is to use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    1 <=
    CASE
        WHEN aa NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        THEN CONVERT(int, aa)
        ELSE 0
    END;
```

Intermediate materialization is not a supported technique, so it should only be employed by very expert users in special circumstances where the risks are understood and accepted.

`TOP 100 PERCENT` is generally [ignored by the optimizer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx) in SQL Server 2005 onward.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the TOP clause into the inner query, you're forcing SQL Server to run that query first before it runs the outer query - thereby discarding all rows for which ISNUMERIC returns false.

Without the TOP clause, the optimiser can rewrite the query to be the same as your first query.